# Conditional Probability Distribution

Tags: probability

Let x and y denote the values of two consecutive die roles(6 sided). U=min(x,y) V=max(x,y). Determine the conditional probability mass function for U given V=v.

Answer (score 0):

Consider all the outcomes:

```
11 12 13 14 15 16 
21 22 23 24 25 26
31 32 33 34 35 36
41 42 43 44 45 46
51 52 53 54 55 56
61 62 63 64 65 66
```

Given $V= v$ (for example $v=4$), you are in one of the following cases:

```
         14
         24
         34
41 42 43 44
```

There are $v^2 -(v-1)^2 = 2v-1$ of them.

You get just counting, that
$$
P(U = u|V=v)  = \begin{cases}
\frac 2{2v-1} & \text{if }u<v
\\
\frac 1{2v-1} & \text{if }u=v
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: can you be a little more explicit?

Comment: I am sorry Did, I don't get it.

Comment: Aaargh... I erred. Sorry about the noise (goes back hiding under a rock while weeping).